# Back button on toolbar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitoolbar

I am working on a webview, and I noticed there is no Back or Next system button for the toolbar. I'm asking this because I see it for the nav bar, and in safari on an iPhone. So if someone could clear this up for me, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

first I suggest you to take a look at apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/)

As for the navigation buttons: create a toolbar or smth else depends on design, and add necessary buttons(back/forward etc) actions in your .swift file

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: UIBarButtonItem-or-UIButton) {
    self.webView.goBack()
}

@IBAction func reload(sender: UIBarButtonItem-or-UIButton) {
    self.webView.reload()
}

@IBAction func forward(sender: UIBarButtonItem-or-UIButton) {
    self.webView.goForward()
}
```